# How to split the array into smaller one by a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains the values which is shown below :

```
Array
(
    Array
    ( 
        Array(TRANS, 3434343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 67787, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 788998, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 67676, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TRANS, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 34355, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 676788, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 232323, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TRANS, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, fgfgfggf, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
    )
)

Array
(
    Array
    (
        Array(TRANS, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TRANS, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TRANS, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
        Array(TXPRICE, 344343, 345, 56657667)
    )
)
```

There can be multiple arrays.

I wanted to separate the first 'TRANS' with its corresponding 'TXPRICE' to a separate array till the next 'TRANS' which is stored as the next array.

I have done some coding but it is not working. I tried to check it with the TRANS field but it is not working.

I wanted to change the above array to the form as shown below :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => TRANS
                [1] => 34343545
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 455456556
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 34556656776
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 676767887
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 343434343
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 89989898
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 34455455
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 6566776
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 345789
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 454566
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 4544
                [2] => 345
                [3] => 345666
            )
    )
[1] => Array(   

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => TRANS
                [1] => 343435
                [2] => 345
                [3] => 566777
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 3455
                [2] => 566
                [3] => 232334
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 345566
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 345666767
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 433434
                [2] => 234
                [3] => 455454
            )
)
[2] => Array(

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => TRANS
                [1] => 4343433
                [2] => 3434
                [3] => 566676776
                
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 33434343
                [2] => 334
                [3] => 4345454
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 7676676
                [2] => 002
                [3] => 545445
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => TXPRICE
                [1] => 3433443
                [2] => 55665
                [3] => 45454
            )

    )
)
```

The code which I had done is given below :

```
for($l=0;$l<count($transaction);$l++){

            for($m=0;$m<count($transaction[$l]);$m++){
                
                
                for ($n = 0; $n < count($transaction[$l][$m]); $i++) {
                if ($transaction[$l][$m][0] == "TRANS") $next++;
                $result[$next][$n] = $transaction[$l][$m];
                } 

                

            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I have added the code..But its logic is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to achieve it. At the end `$res` variable
contains your expected result.

```
$res = [];
$i = -1;

foreach($transaction as $item) {
    if ($item[0] == 'TRANS') {
        $res[$i++] = [$item];
    } else if ($res[$i]) {
        array_push($res[$i], $item);
    }
}
```

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: @annababu could you please provide me the array in PHP format (not var_dumped)
I will run it here and update my code accordingly

Comment: Sure..I will update it here itself.

Comment: Hi..I have updated the actual array not the var_dumped array

Comment: It is not valid PHP syntax, and this payload is not the same as described in the question. you have "TRANSACTN" instead of "TRANS" in some cases, also you have multiple Arrays defined that are not wrapped with one top-level Array.

Comment: Sorry..Corrected. Pls check.